# Simulate the click of a ribbon button from another VSTO addin in Word

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

I have a third party addin that puts a number of buttons on the word ribbon. I have my own VSTO addin that I have added which contains a button. On the button press of my button I would like to perform my action and then simulate the press of the third party button. I know how the get as far as creating the button and addin my own functionality its just the simulation of clicking the third party button that I don't know how to do. This is my first VSTO addin so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The only access your code has is the same as what the user has: this would be the Alt+ keyboard shortcut assigned to the key. To "press" that keyboard combination one uses `SendKeys` which is notoriously unreliable. Add to that the fact that Word can change the keyboard shortcut from one minute to the next, depending on what keyboard shortcuts are assigned to Ribbon buttons by both itself, as well as any custom Ribbon in order to avoid assignment conflicts. In short, there is no reliable way to activate code from another's add-in and this is by design.

Comment: You could ask the third-party if they would expose there commands publicly so that your code can call the procedures the "normal" way.

Comment: Not ideal but maybe you could use the UI Automation APIs...

Comment: Yes I was coming to similar conclusion myself. thanks for the feedback

Comment: @John Did you manage somehow to click on that button?